# Horizontal list with select box

Tags: css, list, select, html-lists

I am using the `<ul><li>` list tag within which I have 3  tags like sos:

```
<ul id="reg-lists" >
    <li class="one">
            <select>...</select>
        </li> 
    <li class="two">
            <select>...</select>
        </li> 
    <li class="three">
            <select>...</select>
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

I have the proper css to make the list horizontal:

```
#the-form li {
    display:inline !important;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 10px;    
}
```

I does'nt seem to work though and am not sure why. Horizontal rule seems to apply well until you put the  combos. Would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: It works in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/7t9cb/ I suppose that `#the-form` exists

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me -- [see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhbha/) -- the list items are displayed horizontally, at least they are when I look at it in Firefox.

If you're seeing something else in another browser, please let us know.

If this is case, the solution may be to use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:inline`.

`inline-block` is similar to `inline`, but allows the element to contain block type elements, which are not allowed by the normal `display:inline` style.

Hope that helps.

Comment: inline-block is not fully supported.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - it is supported sufficiently to use it. The only browsers that matter that have problems are IE6 and IE7, and even in those browsers, it works in the context of this question. `inline-block` *is* ready for use.

Comment: Ya at my work we're required to fully support IE7 still. It's a plague of a browser - almost as bad as IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `<ul>` a set width which is equal to the width of all the combined `<li>`'s and then set your `<li>`'s to `float:left;`

Comment: Yes, for me turns out that the <ul> width was the problem, the rest remained the same. Thank you all, hope this helps someone else out there.